# Is there any other similar file format like BLIF?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

I bump into [Cingulata](https://github.com/CEA-LIST/Cingulata) project which uses [Berkeley Logic Interchange Format (BLIF)](https://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~supratik/courses/cs226/spr16/blif.pdf) to represent circuit. I find `BLIF` file format is a very human-friendly text file format and easy to understand, and am curious to know whether there are other similar text file formats. But after some googling, I can't find a counterpart like `BLIF` file. Besides `BLIF` file, is there any other similar file format? Very sorry for this layman question.

Comment: It would be better if you describe what you are looking for specifically rather than saying "something like BLIF". I have no idea what BLIF looks like, and I don't care, but I know about many other circuit file formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, there are. You can have all kinds of RTLs:

- basic SPICE-style NET files, you can have
- gate networks "backconverted" to a HDL (Verilog, VHDL),
- AIGER
- BTOR
- **EDIF**
- InterSynth…

And of course, all the proprietary RTLs of the FPGA vendors.